# How to create a Scroll Button?

Tags: javascript, html, horizontal-scrolling

I'm working on horizontal website. I would like to create 2 buttons (left button and right button) which can help users to scroll to left and right.

[The site that I'm working on](http://www.kidzstorystudio.com/sample/)

**The functionality that I wanted to create is, when I mouseover the button the page will start and continue the scrolling action until the mouse move away from the button then the page stop scrolling.**

I found something from codepen "http://goo.gl/uTQdzD" that is similar to what I looking for but that is not function in the way I wanted. It's required to keep clicking it only it can continue scroll, once it clicked then it only move a certain pixels distances and stop then have to click again... even I tried to change to mouseover, the same thing... I have to moving the mouse in and out the button only it can continue to scroll the page.

I'm not a professional web coder or developer but just a new guy. I Hope someone out here could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just google a bit before you ask us. http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: So, what are you looking for then?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help here... But I'm not looking for a custom scrollbar, I wanted to create custom image button to scroll the page with just mouse over it and just stop scrolling when mouse leave and also kindly look into the codepen link and read my question again, thanks 

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://codepen.io/caseybaggz/pen/uBysA?editors=001

I changed the `.click` to a `mouseenter` event which is what you are looking for. Additionally, the increments that you noticed were happening because of the `step` variable being assigned `400`. So, I just replaced the `400` with `wWidth` and within the mouseenter function, told it to scroll the `bodyWidth`.

I'm not totally sure why you would want to do this? The natural flow of web design is to design/build sites vertically. To have the user scroll horizontally is a little awkward regarding the UX and could be considered bad design…especially now that devices come into play.

Be sure to learn web-design and UX standards first before you get into a position for developing sites. It not only helps to contribute for bettering the web, but also the UX. ;)

Hope this helps and good luck!